# OpenMP Task Dependency Ignored?

Tags: c++, task, openmp

First of, here's the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 100;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task depend (in: x)
            { x += 1; }

            #pragma omp task depend (out: x)
            { x *= 2; }            
        }
    }
    printf("x = %d\n", x); // prints 202
}
```

From what I understand, `task depend(in: x)` should wait for anything with `depend(out: x)`, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening.

In this particular case, the output is `202` suggesting that `x` was incremented first and then doubled.

In fact, I have tried both in/out and out/in, as well as switching the order in which the tasks themselves are defined. Regardless of in/out dependencies, the tasks always execute top to bottom.

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of `task depend`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation is doing the correct thing.

Apart from the order that is established through the `depend` clause, also the position of the task creation in the source code has an impact on the dependency.

In your example, the first task has an `in` dependency on the `x` variable.  As there's no existing task in the queues that has an `out` or `inout` dependency for the same variable, the task is ready to execute immediately and the implementation will likely do so even before the second task is encountered.

If I exchange the two tasks:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 100;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task depend (out: x)
            { x *= 2; }
            #pragma omp task depend (in: x)
            { x += 1; }
        }
    }
    printf("x = %d\n", x); // prints 201
}
```

The code prints 201, as expected.  I tested this with the Intel Compiler 18.0.3.

The correct modeling of the task dependences for your code would look like this:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 100;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task depend (inout: x)
            { x *= 2; }
            #pragma omp task depend (inout: x)
            { x += 1; }
        }
    }
    printf("x = %d\n", x); // prints 201
}
```

The code still prints 202, but now the dependences correctly model the actual usages of `x`: task 1 reads the old value of `x` and modifies it, so it should use an `inout` dependence.  Task 2 also reads `x` and modifies it, so it should also use an `inout` dependence.

Comment: Your two snippets are identical and you might want to update the `// prints` comment.